# laravel routes and controller view architecture

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am working with Laravel for a new project, and I am wanting to setup a new URL,

`/project/create`

I thought this would be as easy as doing the following,

```
<?php

class Project_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public function action_create()
    {
        return "Step 1";
    }

}
```

However this returns a 404, can you not just setup an url base on /controller/action is this not the case, will I have to do this,

```
Route::get('/project/create', function()
{
    return View::make('project.index');
});
```

or similar for every URL/request the site needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do controller routing.

**Option 1:**

```
// Register a specific controller
Route::controller('project');
```

**Option 2** (not recommended in Laravel 3 as known to be buggy sometimes):

```
 // Register all controllers and all routes
 Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```

You can see [more options about routing and controller routing here](http://www.laravel.com/docs/routing#the-basics)